# Windows server 2012 rdp drops connections

Tags: windows

Windows 7 clients and windows 2012 server. Mapped drive disconnects and reconnects sporadically. Server and client on local lan. Rdp to server also disconnects and reconnects. Ping doesn’t drop and you tube video doesn’t drop. This has worked for a year just fine. Have changed switch, cables and updated all server drivers. No packet drops on server nic test, no errors on switch ports.

Answer (score 4):

You may try to enable **RDP Keep-Alives** and then restart your Windows 7 client. This can be done in local group policy using **gpedit.msc**.

**Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Connections -> Configure keep-alive connection interval** set to **Enabled**

Set the **Keep-Alive interval** to **1**

After making the above changes and restarting test whether you are able to maintain a connection. Hope this helps.